# Exlain the significance of the uniform random variable for the simulation of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, simulation

I can think of the "Universality of the Uniform":

> Given an Unif(0,1) r.v., we can construct an r.v. with any cts
>   distribution we want. Conversely, given an r.v. with an arbitrary cts
>   distribution, we can create a Unif(0,1).
>   ----From *[Introduction to Probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466575573)* by J.K.Blitzstein & J.Hwang.

Other than this "*Universality of the Uniform*" or "*Fundamental theorem of Simulation*", is there any other (potentially in more depth) explanation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen the inverse cdf sampling method?

Comment: @Chinny84, hi thanks for comment. Yes, in some way, basically that is where we use uniformly r.v. to construct other r,v.?